# How to present the sql '.' in php

Tags: php, mysql

The sql I put in php

```
$sql = 'select * from table_1 where Right(col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1))';
```

However the '.' the $sql would become

```
select * from table_1 where Right(col_1, LOCATE(,col_1))
```

because of the '.'

How to present '.' , when I put it in php

Comment: Why are you using `where (col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1))` instead of `where LOCATE('.',col_1)` ?

Answer (score 3):

This should be like...

```
$sql = "select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('.', col_1))";
```

In your case you are `concatenating` two string -

1. `select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE(`
2. `,col_1))`

Answer (score 3):

use double quotes around the string

```
$sql = "select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1))";
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use escape characters

```
$sql = 'select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE(\'.\',col_1))';
```

Or you may use double quoting for php

```
$sql = "select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1))";
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
$sql = "select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1))";
```

Using double quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Either use double quotes for your statement or escape the single quotes.

```
$sql = "select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('.',col_1))";
```

Or

```
$sql = 'select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE(\'.\',col_1))';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it : (concatenation)

```
$sql = 'select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('.'.,col_1))';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$sql = sprintf("select * from table_1 where (col_1, LOCATE('%s',col_1))",
                mysql_real_escape_string('.'));
```